# Web scraping, can't get the href of a tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this Page https://rarity.tools/thecryptodads
Using Selenium in python.

At the top of the right of each card below, there's the owner name that contains a link once pressed, it takes you to that owner's page.

When I inspect the element I can clearly see the a tag with the href link as shown below:

[image]

However, When I try to scrape it. it gets neither that text within the a tag nor the href.
I tried to get the div above it which contains this a tag along with another div that contains the number on the card located top left, but when I get the innerText of the div. it only gets the text of the first div AKA the number. (prints 1 for the first card).

here's the code on how I'm trying to get the link:

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://rarity.tools/thecryptodads")

try:
    click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a"))
    )
    print(click.text)
except:
    print()
```

I tried to get the item by class name, css selector, xpath, full xpath. still cant get the href.
BUT when I go into the debug mood and go through it line by line, I can see that this object is holding the text I want and it prints it at the end of the execution. which is so weird to me. I assume that this text is using some sort of encryption! that prevents me form scaping it!

Comment: "To scrap" means to discard or shred something. The word you are looking for is "to scrape", which means to peel off or push together something, by extension extracting information from a web page.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I apologize. I just wanted to post an image to give a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Website is taking time to load all the attribute values.

There are two ways to get that output.

1: Apply `time.sleep(10)` after `driver.get(URL)`.

```
driver.get("https://rarity.tools/thecryptodads")
time.sleep(10)

ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'flex-1')]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")
print(ele.get_attribute("href"))
print(ele.text)
```

2: Apply `Explicit wait` till the `href` attribute has a value starting from `https`.

```
driver.get("https://rarity.tools/thecryptodads")
wait= WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'flex-1')]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[contains(@href,'https')]")))
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'flex-1')]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")
print(ele.get_attribute("href"))
print(ele.text)
```

Output for both 1 and 2:

```
https://opensea.io/accounts/0x8f612b1a1afcc4a55879bb02212454ae79cab04b?ref=0x5c5321ae45550685308a405827575e3d6b4a84aa
0x8f61
```

Its better to go for Relative xpath compared to Absolute.

Comment: you provided the solution and the explanation I need. now it makes perfect sense to me and learned new things. Thank you so much and thanks to all of the people who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

when you're using ".text" you'll get the text value of the element.
To find the 'href' attribute of the 'a' tag. you'll need to use ".get_attribute('href')".
In your case `click.get_attribute('href')`.

Comment: sorry for not adding this to the post. I did try get_attribute(href) still didn't work. it prints nothing. I have the whole project finished. only stuck at this issue. if you try to run my code you will get that it wont print it

Comment: @Alaa I do get the href using your code and with `click.get_attribute('href')`. Try it in another way using `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` and `time.sleep()` (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
# catching that particular element with its xpath
click = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__layout']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[11]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a").get_attribute("href")

# extracting the href of that element
href = click.get_attribute("href")

print(href)
```

Output:

```
https://rarity.tools/nfh
```

Comment: I did try that. I tried every possible way, I tried to get the text and then use find_element_by_link_text() or partial link. i tried get_attribute("innerText"). nothing works.

Comment: @Alaa please check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for trying it out. but that's not the link I need. if you look at the a tag. it has this link: 
https://opensea.io/accounts/0x8f612b1a1afcc4a55879bb02212454ae79cab04b?ref=0x5c5321ae45550685308a405827575e3d6b4a84aa
0x8f61
that's the one I need. i got it solved tho. thank u

Answer (score 0):

Actually data is also  generating from api calls json response.  Here is the working example:

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'}


data = []
r = requests.get('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?asset_contract_address=0xecdd2f733bd20e56865750ebce33f17da0bee461&limit=20&token_ids=1552&token_ids=4191&token_ids=9123&token_ids=3428&token_ids=8334&token_ids=5819&token_ids=5593&token_ids=3592&token_ids=7731&token_ids=257&token_ids=2290&token_ids=2259&token_ids=6103&token_ids=4778&token_ids=3309&token_ids=1787&token_ids=7684&token_ids=8322&token_ids=2464&token_ids=2389')

for item in r.json()['assets']:
    data.append ([
        item['name'],
        item['token_id']
        ])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "token_id"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                Name           token_id
0          Shredded Dad #9123     9123
1                OG Dad #8334     8334
2             CryptoDad #8322     8322
3             CryptoDad #7684     7684
4             CryptoDad #7731     7731
5             CryptoDad #6103     6103
6             CryptoDad #5819     5819
7             CryptoDad #5593     5593
8             CryptoDad #4778     4778
9            FrankenDad #4191     4191
10            CryptoDad #3592     3592
11          Diamond Dad #3428     3428
12            CryptoDad #3309     3309
13            CryptoDad #2464     2464
14            CryptoDad #2389     2389
15            CryptoDad #2290     2290
16            CryptoDad #2259     2259
17            CryptoDad #1787     1787
18  Abducted Beer Belly #1552     1552
19             CryptoDad #257      257
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look up the API and providing an example for me. But I need the automation process more than the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why `.get_attribute('href')` is just giving me `https://rarity.tools/thecryptodads#` url which is not the desired output.

Also `ActionChains` are for to let Selenium see the web element in UI.

as a workaround what I did was to `click` the `link`, and it opened in a `new tab` then from there I could get the `link`.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://rarity.tools/thecryptodads")
try:
    ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'flex-grow font-extrabold')]//following-sibling::a")))
    action.move_to_element(ele).perform()
    print(ele.get_attribute('href'))
    time.sleep(5)
    ele.click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(5)
    print(driver.current_url)
except:
    print("Something else")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output :**

```
https://rarity.tools/thecryptodads#
https://opensea.io/accounts/0x8f612b1a1afcc4a55879bb02212454ae79cab04b?ref=0x5c5321ae45550685308a405827575e3d6b4a84aa
```

Comment: WOW, It works. it does what I want. but I want to learn. Why that tag couldn't be scrapped!